# Check multiple conditions in `if` using for loop

Tags: python

I have to check for multiple 'and' conditions in if
Eg:

```
if (a[1]==b[1]) and (a[2]==b[2]) and (a[3]==b[3]) and (a[4]==b[4]):
```

can I do above using for loop in if, say something like

```
if (a[i]==b[i] for i in range(0,4)):
```

Above suggested won't work as it sets the condition as true even if one of them is true.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: so you want to check if 2 arrays or lists are the same?

Comment: Here a and b are dictionaries. for i in range(0,4) could be substituted to for parameter in parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) here:

```
if all(a[i]==b[i] for i in range(1, 5)):
```

From the document:

> Return `True` if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

And `(a[i]==b[i] for i in range(1, 5))` return a [**generator**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)(it's an iterable), then `all()` return `True` if all elements in that generator is `True`, else `False`. Like your code does.

Comment: @user3798653 if an answer solved your issue, consider accepting it

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
if all(a[i]==b[i] for i in range(1,5)):
    # logic here
```

Usage of `all()`:

1. if all the elements in iterable  are `True` returns `True`
2. if one lement is `False` it return `False`

eg: `all([True,True])` --> `True`
    `all([False,True])`--> `False`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh,Sorry Forgot